# error when including Pinterest SDK in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to include Pinterest android SDK in Android Studio, but I always see the following error message, can somebody help me out, thanks!

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: Please post the build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It's because the pinterest library has an ic_launcher.png in it and I had one myself obviously. Renaming my ic_launcher.png to launcher.png did the trick.